# Getting touchID verification to pop up again

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm currently implementing an app that ONLY accepts touch id as a way to get to the next viewcontroller but as a newbie, I'm not entirely sure how to correctly do this. My current code is as follows:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
LAContext *myContext = [[LAContext alloc] init];
NSError *authError = nil;
NSString *myLocalizedReasonString = @"Please Enter Touch ID";

if ([myContext canEvaluatePolicy:LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics error:&authError]) {
    [myContext evaluatePolicy:LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics
              localizedReason:myLocalizedReasonString
                        reply:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
                            if (success) {
                                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showList" sender:nil];
                                });
                            } else {
                                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                                                        message:@"Authentication is verified through touch only."
                                                                                       delegate:self
                                                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Close"
                                                                              otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
                                    [alertView show];
                                    // Rather than show a UIAlert here, use the error to determine if you should push to a keypad for PIN entry.
                                });
                            }
                        }];
}
```

}

Every time the user hits the "Cancel" button, my app just crashes but I would like it to make the touchID verification reappear. How can i do so? Thanks for your help!

Comment: What is the crash message and which line does it crash on

Comment: @Paulw11 I'm actually not sure where it's crashing (the app just closes on its own after clicking "close". I would assume that in the "else" statement, I would somehow call on the touchid verification again but not sure how to :-(

Comment: Move all this code into another function and call that function from `viewWillAppear`. Then in your else you can just call that function again. Also you should call `super.viewWillAppear`

Comment: thanks that solved my problem